# Is there a need to stir the kettle at some regular interval while boiling the wort?

Tags: wort, boil

I extract brew. After I boil the three gallons of water, I take the kettle off the stove and pour the sugars in, and stir under I'm convinced it has all been dissolved. Placing the kettle back on the stove, I wait until it boils again before I pour in the bittering hops. At this point I do stir a lot, perhaps 3-5 minutes, to make sure that no "solid" part of the hops (I get pellets) would get stuck to the bottom of the kettle.

I do not stir at any time from here to the next hop schedule, where I repeat the 3-5 minute stirring.

Should I be stirring every N minutes, or does it not matter?

Does it matter whether it is extract vs full grain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to stir regularly.

Hops, pellet or otherwise, do float around pretty freely.  I have never heard of hops sticking to the bottom of the pot, nor has it ever happened to me.

I only stir occasionally to get that hop crud of the sides of the pot above the boil line back into the pot.  And I stir to manage the foam early on in the process.

Otherwise your process sounds fine the way it is.

Comment: I use a rubber spatula to wipe the hops crud back into the boil

Comment: If you have a good boil going, keep in mind that is pretty much doing any stirring for you as well. (Not that you need to.)

Comment: I would even say, you don't need to stir at all. At boiling temp your wort is very liquid and the boil itself does the stirring.